# How to get database field type in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel

Is there a way to get the datatype of a database table field?
This would be almost like the inverse of a migration.

For example, if the migration of a users table column looks like

```
...
$table->integer('age')
...
```

Is there a function that will return `integer` if I specify table `user` and column `age`?

I'm not interested in a specific database implementation, (`mysql_field_type()`).  Like Laravel's migration, it needs to be database agnostic.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way using the Schema builder.

Comment: Hey Rubens, See answer below. Thanks though :)

Comment: Nice! I just limit myself to the Schema builder, but indeed, Doctrine can provide a lot of info.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

***For Laravel 4:***

After digging in Laravel, this is what I got.

`DB::connection()->getDoctrineColumn('users', 'age')->getType()->getName()`

Comment: whoops you totally beat me to it :D

Comment: Wow, you two beat me too.

Comment: Not work on laravel 5.2 because a problem with Doctrine issue. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3116 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14447

Comment: @abkrim you'll need to run `composer require doctrine/dbal` to install the dependency.

Comment: @HaoLuo link not about do you speak. Doctrine issue is because not support Enum types.

Comment: This returns string not varchar etc. for me

Comment: This doesn't support jsonb. Any other alternative when I have an attribute that is a jsonb on my table?

Comment: Returns "string", but how do we get length?

Comment: @Todd did you see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46574742/1575353)?

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ yes. Thanks. And thanks for the blast back to Laravel -- I've been using NodeJS and React almost exclusively for the last 2 years. I think I posted that comment for a colleague.

Answer (score 21):

## For Laravel 5.2 - 9.x

use [`Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::getColumnType()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_getColumnType)

```
DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnType($tableName, $colName)
```

e.g.

```
$ageType = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnType('user', 'age')
```

You may need to run this command if you haven't already:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: Here is what works:                 ```$column_type = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnType($model->getTable(), $column_name);```
after updating composer to         ```"doctrine/dbal": "~2.6"```

Comment: Thanks - I updated my answer; My team uses `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::connection()` to specify which connection is needed, and that returns the `\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder` instance... thanks for helping me generalize this.

Comment: yeah you got me started on the right answer. i switched to an up vote. thanks.

Comment: composer require doctrine/dbal

Answer (score 10):

### Short answer: Yes, that functionality exists

After scouring the code, I found that you could. Skip below to **"The Solution"** to see it.

Eloquent, and the Database classes, use PDO, which does not tie you a specific SQL-based database.

Therefore, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$pdo = DB::getPdo();
```

Note that the connection object can [return the instance of PDO](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L646).

There are some methods like [getColumnMeta](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php), **but they aren't fully supported across all drivers**.

**However**, some googling seems to point out that the best way might be to use [ANSI-standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) - using sql queries to get that information.

### The solution

**Lastly**, Laravel includes the Doctrine library as a dependency, which does contain some [schema functionality](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html).

> Sidenote: Doctrine is, in fact, included for its schema-based functionalities - Laravel doesn't use Doctrine's ORM

See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L622) on the same connection object where we retrieved the PDO instance, we can get the doctrine connection and schema manager. You should be able to call:

```
$schema = DB:: getDoctrineSchemaManager();
```

You can then use the schema manager ([docs here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html)) to get what you're after.

Answer (score 9):

**GET All Details of fields of table**

```
DB::select('describe table_name');
```

**Example:-**

```
DB::select('describe users');
```

**Response will be like this**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => id
            [Type] => int(11)
            [Null] => NO
            [Key] => PRI
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => auto_increment
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => user_group_id
            [Type] => int(11) unsigned
            [Null] => YES
            [Key] => MUL
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Field] => username
            [Type] => varchar(100)
            [Null] => YES
            [Key] => MUL
            [Default] => 
            [Extra] => 
        )
 )
```

Answer (score 9):

In **Laravel 5+ (including 6 and 7)**, you can get the db table column metadata (ie type, default value etc) in the following way:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

For all columns:

```
 $columns = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableColumns('table_name');
 $column = Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineColumn('table_name'', 'column_name'); //For a single column:
```

`getDoctrineSchemaManager` method returns a array of `\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column` Class Instances.

`getDoctrineColumn` method returns the instance of `\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column` class.

Couple of methods from `\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Column` class:

```
$column->getName();
$column->getNotnull(); // returns true/false
$column->getDefault(); 
$column->getType(); 
$column->getLength();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression with a dial-down function to show you array details of all your table's fields:

```
dd(DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW FIELDS FROM tablename')));
```

Comment: Simplest and most effective solution.

Answer (score 4):

I use this with laravel 4.1,,

```
$schema = \DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager();
$tables = $schema->listTables();

foreach ($tables as $table) {
    echo "<i>".$table->getName() . " </i><b>columns:</b><br>";
    foreach ($table->getColumns() as $column) {
        echo ' - ' . $column->getName() . " - " . $column->getType()->getName() . "<br>";
    }
}
```

or to get specific table use this: `$columns = $schema->listTableColumns('user');`

Answer (score 2):

### Within the model: laravel5.x

```
    $temp = $this->newQuery()->fromQuery("SHOW FIELDS FROM ".$this->getTable());

    foreach($temp as $val){
       echo 'Field: '.$val->Field;
       echo 'Type: '.$val->Type;
   }
```

Comment: I was looking for eloquent method, thanks dear

Answer (score 1):

The most simplest way is :-

```
$data = DB::table('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS')
                    ->select('DATA_TYPE')
                    ->where('TABLE_NAME', 'users')
                    ->where('COLUMN_NAME', 'age')
                    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing:

```
DB::connection()->getDoctrineColumn($tableName, $colName)
    ->getType()
    ->getName();
```

It works on Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel 10:

```
$columns = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::getColumns('<table name here>');
$definition = current(array_filter($columns, function($column) {
    return $column['name'] === '<column name here>';
}));
```

result:

```
[
  'name' => 'id',
  'type_name' => 'bigint',
  'type' => 'bigint(20) unsigned',
  'collation' => NULL,
  'nullable' => false,
  'default' => NULL,
  'auto_increment' => true,
  'comment' => '',
]
```