# Get Query Field Info in Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, is there a way to get the field info based on the results of a query?

I can do this in pure PHP/MySQL, but I'd like to make sure there isn't a way to do this within the Laravel framework before going that route.

Below is an example from PHP's site illustrating the `fetch_fields()` function.  I'm interested in finding out if there's a Laravel equivalent approach in getting the results from the `fetch_fields()` function as in the example below.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Name, SurfaceArea from Country ORDER BY Code LIMIT 5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* Get field information for all columns */
    $finfo = $result->fetch_fields();

    foreach ($finfo as $val) {
        printf("Name:     %s\n", $val->name);
        printf("Table:    %s\n", $val->table);
        printf("max. Len: %d\n", $val->max_length);
        printf("Flags:    %d\n", $val->flags);
        printf("Type:     %d\n\n", $val->type);
    }
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: As far as I know, nothing like this exists. But perhaps somebody else has a deeper knowledge on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is exactly what you want, although it could help. This SO answer [How to get database field type in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562684/how-to-get-database-field-type-in-laravel) mentions using doctrines schema manager:

```
$schema = DB:: getDoctrineSchemaManager();
```

Which will then allow you to perform various methods such as the one you mention. See the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html) for that.

Other than that, the functionality isn't included and you will have to roll your own as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see that answer, but I want to base it on a select statement rather than a table.  I think you're right, I'll have to roll my own.