# How to get columns properties in Eloquent orm?

Tags: php, laravel

I want get the columns properties(column type, charset etc.) from table in Eloquent orm. how i can did this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [laravel 4 -> get column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951787/laravel-4-get-column-names)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:

```
DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM users'));
```

Comment: this is the raw quey. you question was for elequent. After few minutes searching on stackoverflow I found a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562684/how-to-get-database-field-type-in-laravel . Anyway [Describe Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/describe.html) may more powrfull then   `SHOW COLUMNS`

Comment: `DB::select` takes a raw query. No need to call `DB::raw` again.