# Laravel: How to get table column name, its type and length

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Is there any method available in Laravel 5/5.1, through which we can get the Table columns name, its type and length, Means table meta data?

eg:

```
Name    |    Type    |    Length

ID      |    Integer |    11
Name    |    varchar |    100
Email   |    varchar |    100
Password|    md5     |    82
Address |    tinytext|    
DOB     |    date    |    
Status  |    enum(0,1)|
```

Comment: Possible repetition: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951787/laravel-4-get-column-names

Comment: I am not getting my desire results, I got the columns name but not Type and its length

Comment: Ok, then look here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562684/how-to-get-database-field-type-in-laravel (did you made any research effort?)

Comment: Yes, I am doing my research,

Comment: Doing your research doesn't mean asking people on SO about something you can find on your own in 5 minutes..

Answer (score 4):

I attempted this but kept getting PDO errors because not all drivers are supported. So if you use MySQL or MariaDB this may help.

```
$columns = DB::select( DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM `'.$table.'`'));

foreach($columns as $column) {
    $name = $column->Name;
    $type = $column->Type;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check it here. https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html

Sample code for getting type of password field from users table.

```
dd(DB::connection()->getDoctrineColumn('users', 'password')->getType()->getName());
```

I'll leave the rest to you. Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've added to my larger models at the beginning of projects is a handy static function which returns all table columns data as an array so it can be used with Tinker or otherwise:

```
public static function describe()
{
    return DB::select(DB::raw("DESCRIBE " . (new self)->getTable(). ";"));
}
```

Then call this in tinker or otherwise with App\Models\ModelName::describe()

Comment: The first comment on the question links to a similar question and its accepted answer provides a *Laravel* specific method. Note that your answer is database-driver specific as with one of the other answers. The Laravel documentation has this resource https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_getColumnListing providing `getColumnListing(string $table)`.