# Undefined index: COMMENTS

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5, dbal

Basically i want to get column listings and types
I’m using 
    `$this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing(‘table’);`
To get column listing and it’s working without any problem, however when i tried to get column type using

```
$this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnType(‘table’,’column’);
```

It didn’t work at first, then i installed dbal package now i am getting this error

> Undefined index: COMMENTS
>   Vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\OracleSchemaManager.php:402

```
Public function listTableDetails($tableName):table
{
    $table=parent::listTableDetails($tableName);
    $sql = $platform->getListTableCommentSQL($tableName);
    $tableOptions=$this->_conn->fetchAssoc($sql);
    $table->addOptions(‘comment’, $tableOptions[‘COMMENTS’]);

    return table;
}
```

I have no clue what’s wrong, comments is not anything in my db!!!

Comment: COMMENTS maybe related to comments which we make on column in the database.

Comment: Okay if that so! What am supposed to do to avoid this error? Am i suppose to define a variable called comments?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562684/how-to-get-database-field-type-in-laravel

Comment: Also what is there in these lines OracleSchemaManager.php:402?

Comment: I’ve seen this already, i edited my question and added the dbal function where the error is, thanks

Comment: The thing is the code works just fine if i commented the table->addOption line in dbal package in oracleschemamanager.php!!!! 
For some reason addoption is the cause of all this and i have no clue what is the purpose of this line! Or how to bypass this error without commenting it

Comment: there was a bug in the doctrine package  i had to go to the source code of the package and re-write comments in lower case and it works, I don’t know why or how it works but this was my solution