# How to get all field type from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Using laravel 8. I have an issue with get column type of field from database !  if I want to get all field type of tables . I have a users table and field such as data type, Collation, Attributes , etc.

TableController

```
public function show($table)
{
    $tables = Schema::getColumnListing($table);
    return view('tables.show', compact('tables'))->with('i');
}
```

I want to get like this

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562684/how-to-get-database-field-type-in-laravel/46574742 This might answer your question

Comment: @dqureshiumar I have tried already, but still not too1

Comment: This would be a good start - $sql = 'SELECT * from information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "database_name" AND TABLE_NAME = "users"';$results = DB::select($sql); Log::info($results);

Comment: @mightyteja now I have fixed already !

Comment: @Nak Glad you were able to find the answer. if you have fixed the issue without comments help, please make sure you add the solution as answer. It would be hepful for someone in future.

Comment: @mightyteja I have tried to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562684/how-to-get-database-field-type-in-laravel/46574742